# VBA Copy filled cells in selected range in all sheets within the workbook to one summary sheet

Tags: vba, excel, macros

could anybody help please? I was searching for VBA macro which will help me to summarize data from many forms. But I didnt find anything which is working for me.

I have workbook with huge number of sheets. The sheets are forms, which were filled by customers (each sheet is called FORM_number).
The problem is that people didnt fill up the forms in normal order - starting from the top row (in my case A5) but in a range (A5:K30) anywhere (example in row starting in A:10 and then A:15 and then A:22 and A:23). 
The task which the macro should do, is to  copy only filled rows in the mentioned range (example: only row 10,15,22,23) and paste it to "Summary_Sheet" one by one - so 4 records from 1st form then 7 records from 2nd form etc. And it should also add the number (from form name) to the column L to each record which was copied from that sheet.

Not sure if I am clear enough, but if somebody will have time to help, I will be very grateful.

Comment: You could select the filled cells with VBA's [`SpecialCells`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157.aspx) range type.  Then, copy/paste to the next sheet, to the next available row. There are many questions about doing this on SO alone.  What have you tried though? What has/hasn't worked?

Comment: I was trying to use this manual http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24792525/copying-ranges-from-one-sheet-into-another-using-a-loop-of-sheet-names
but it didn't  work. Since I am not VBA master I dont know what to update so it works on my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edited after OP's clarification about *initial* input row index:

you could try this (commented) code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim sht As Worksheet, summarySht As Worksheet
    Dim rngToCopy  As Range

    With Workbooks("Forms") '<--| change "formsWb" to your actual workbook with "FORM_Number" sheets name
        Set summarySht = GetOrCreateSheet(.Worksheets, "Summary_Sheet") '<--|get Summary worksheet reference or create it if not already in referenced workbook
        For Each sht In .Worksheets '<-- loop through referenced workbook worksheets
            With sht '<-- reference current worksheet
                If Left(.name, 5) = "FORM_" Then '<-- if its name begins with "FORM_" then...
                    Set rngToCopy = .Columns(1).SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeConstants).EntireRow '<-- set the range of currently referenced worksheet column "A" not blank cell entire row
                    Set rngToCopy = Intersect(rngToCopy, .Rows("5:" & .UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count).row)) '<--| limit it to rows from row 5 downwards
                    rngToCopy.Copy '<-- copy the above set range
                    With summarySht '<-- reference Summary worksheet
                        With .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1) '<-- get its first blank cell in column "A"
                            .PasteSpecial '<-- paste the copied range
                            Application.CutCopyMode = False
                            .Offset(, 11).Resize(.Parent.Cells(.Parent.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row - .row + 1).Value = sht.name '<-- paste the current "FORM" worksheet name in column "L" corresponding rows
                        End With
                    End With
                End If
            End With
        Next sht
    End With
End Sub

Function GetOrCreateSheet(wss As sheets, shtName As String) As Worksheet
    With wss
        On Error Resume Next
        Set GetOrCreateSheet = .Item(shtName)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If GetOrCreateSheet Is Nothing Then
            Set GetOrCreateSheet = .Add
            .Parent.ActiveSheet.name = "Summary_Sheet"
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Wow, thank you! Its almost what I need. Just one question, how I can add the range which should be checked on filled/blank cells? You know, the forms have also some header, and I need to copy just data which was filled by customers - which is from 5th row - so I want it evaluate just the specified range.

Comment: how can I modify this please?
 Set rngToCopy = .Columns(1).SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeConstants).EntireRow

Comment: you want `rngToCopy` start from a specific row (not row 1)?

Comment: Absolutely perfect!! Thank you very much.